# Dynamic div scale over image

Tags: html, css

Im trying for some time the fix this issue. Its coded with html and css. 
In short description: i want to to see all divs over the image when scale the browser window. There is a problem when resize the window vertically here is the images:
[image: Normal view]

[image: Gugged view]

```
In the css i have like this code for every box:
#map > .screen > .upr {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    top: 51.5%;
    left: 19%;
}
```

and this is for the image

```
#map > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-60%);
}
```

Any chance to link me any tutorial for this?

UPDATE 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_map.css">
        <?php require 'favicon.php' ?>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table_box">  
            <div id="inner"><div class="logo"><p><a href="gentable_1.php">Example</a></div></div><br> 
        </div>
        <div id = "map">
            <img src = "bg_bic.jpg" />
            <div class = "screen">
                <div class='drop-shadow-red iskar'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='Iskar.php' ><img   class='img-blink' src='red.png' alt='Внимание повреда!' /> ЯР </p></a></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow upr'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='./HQ.php' ><b> 1 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow batak'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='./Batak.php' ><b> 2 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow kalin'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='./Kalin.php' ><b> 3 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow petrohan'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href=''><b> 4 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow bel'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href=''><b> 5 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow beg'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href=''><b> 6 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow rod'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='rodopi.php' ><b> 7 </b></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow vuch'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='QR_Vucha.php' ><b> 8 </b></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow sta'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='./stamboliiski.php' ><b> 9 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow kop'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='./koprinka.php' ><b> 10 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow htka'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='./htk_arda.php' ><b> 11 </b><br /></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow rozk'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href=''><b> 12 </b></а></p></div>
                <div class='drop-shadow ovch'><p class='ptext'><a class='acd' href='./Ovcharitsa.php' ><b> 13</b></а></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

- {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

```
body {
    background-color: #E0E7E9;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    z-index: 98;
}

#map, .table_boxbox {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 50px 10px 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,2)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(6,154,166,0.01), rgba(255,255,255,0.5)); /* Standard syntax */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #069AA6;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ;
    box-shadow:0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ;




}

#map > .screen,
#map > img {display: block; width: auto; max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-60%);
}

#map > .screen > .box1, 
#map > .screen > .box2{
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 56.5%;
    left: 23%;
    text-align: center;
}
.drop-shadow {
    padding: 0.6vh 1vh;
    background: url(images/green.png) no-repeat center left;
    background-position: 8px 50%;
    background-size: 2vh;
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -mox-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
    z-index: 99;
}

.drop-shadow-red {
    padding: 0.6vh 1vh;
    background: url(images/red.png) no-repeat center left;
    background-size: 2vh;  
    background-position: 6px 50%;
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
    font-weight: bold;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -mox-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
    z-index: 99;
}

#map > .screen > .upr {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    top: 51.5%;
    left: 19%;
}

#map > .screen > .batak {
    position: absolute;
    top: 69%;
    left: 31%;
}

#map > .screen > .kalin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 22%;
}

#map > .screen > .petrohan {
    position: absolute;
    top: 39.5%;
    left: 17%;
}

#map > .screen > .bel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 63%;
    left: 27%;
}

#map > .screen > .beg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 71.8%;
    left: 30%;
}

#map > .screen > .rod {
    position: absolute;
    top: 76%;
    left: 31%;
}

#map > .screen > .vuch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 73.9%;
    left: 35%;
}

#map > .screen > .htka {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75.7%;
    left: 49.2%;
}
#map > .screen > .sta {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43%;
    left: 45.5%;
}

#map > .screen > .kop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 47.5%;
}


#map > .screen > .rozk {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65.5%;
    left: 56%;
}

#map > .screen > .ovch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 63%;
    left: 60%;
}

#map > .screen > .legend {
    position: absolute;
    width: 420px;
    top: 80%;
    left: 67%;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 2842/2383) {
    #map > img {
        width: 100vw;
    }

    #map > .screen {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 83.85vw;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 2842/2383) {
    #map > img {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #map > .screen {
        height: 100vh;
        height: 100vw;
    }
}

.table_box {
    height: 117px;
    background: #069AA6;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #0E384A, #069AA6); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #0E384A, #069AA6); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #0E384A, #069AA6); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0E384A, #069AA6); /* Standard syntax */
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 200px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url('images/NEKemblem.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 250px;

}
.logo a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
table_box > inner > logo > p{
    text-align: left;
}
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* -----> links for index_Iskar_OF.php */


.acd {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    font-family:  arial;
    display:block;
    font-size: 0.9vw;
}

.acd:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.acd > img {
    width: 1.8vh;
    height: 1.8vh;
}

.acd > .img-blink{
    animation: blinker 0.5s linear infinite;
}

.drop-shadow2 {
    padding: 0.6vh 1vh;
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -mox-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
    font-weight: bold
}


.ptext {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.normal{
    color: darkgreen;
}

.warning{
    color: red;
}

.warningBlink {   
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

I probably copy some unused css code sorry for that.

Comment: are you trying to vertically align the divs? If so do you know flexbpx?

Comment: First try with `#map > img {display: block; width: auto; max-width: 100%}`

Comment: I don't want to vertically align. For the second comment the div boxes are more proper stylized but again there is align in one line after resize the window

Comment: That's why I've said to add you HTML too. Don't expect to get the solution with CSS only.

Comment: OK. Updated. :)

Comment: I added and min-width: 100%; Its better but the image is stretched